How to dynamically access component properties in Vue 3?
In Vue 2 it used to be possible to dynamically access component properties in template using a computed property that can access all component properties with this keyword:
<script>
(...)
computed: {
    $property() {
      return (key) => this[key]
    },
  },
(...)
</script>

<template>
  {{ $property('foo') }} <!-- if this.foo existed, it would return this.foo here -->
</template>

This is however not working in Vue 3. Doing something similar, i.e.
<script>
(...)
setup(props, ctx) {
  const $property = computed(() => (name) => this[name])

  return {
    $property
  }
})
(...)
</script>

<template>
{{ $property('foo') }}
</template>

throws an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.$property is not a function.
Although when inspected in Vue DevTools, $property actually is a function:

Rewriting $property from computed to a regular function throws the same error.
Is there any workaround that would allow us to dynamically access component properties in templates of Vue 3 components using {{ $property('dynamicPropertyName') }}?

It doesn't work this way. Consider explaining your case. In case you have a limited set of property names, move them to single reactive() object for this purpose. Also $property() doesn't receive the optimizations associated with computeds so it's generally not a good practice

@EstusFlask My case is that I'm upgrading the codebase to Vue 3 and the code was already written this way in Vue 2, so I wanted to avoid refactoring more than necessary. But on second thought, looks like moving all these dynamic properties to a single reactive object is inevitable.

Alternatively, computed property that takes arguments can be converted to regular function instead.

You can refer internals such as getCurrentInstance() but it shouldn't be considered anything but a temporary workaround

All props are already exposed to template.
Instead of $property('foo'), use foo directly. Or you could use $props['foo'], without having to return it from setup function. ($props is always present in a Vue component, even when there are no  declared props).

If you really want to mimic the old Vue 2 code into composition, here's what would work, although it's completely unnecessary, as I pointed out:
export default {
  props: ['foo'],
  setup(props) {
    const property = computed(() => (name) => props[name])

    return {
      property
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
{{ property('foo') }}
</template>

See it here.

I don't want to access props or properties directly. I want to dynamically (without explicitly stating names) access computed getters. I tried const foobar = computed(() => ({...mapGetters('foo', ['bar'])})) but in template it's returning function's content rather than the getter's value, even if I do {{ foobar['bar']() }}

I updated my answer with a working POC on Vue SFC Playground. mapGetters serves a completely different purpose.

Like I said, I don't want to access props, your example is using props.
Access to all properties appears to be possible with: const vm = getCurrentInstance() and then it can be accessed with vm.ctx.
